# Spring Boot / Okta - how to retrieve the users groups

Tags: admin, roles, okta, group, okta-api

I'm trying to find an example of how to get the groups a user belongs to in Okta in a Spring Boot application which uses Okta as its OIDC provider.

So far, I've gotten the user attributes and the Authority (which is alway "ROLE_USER").

But the part I'm missing is to how to get the list of groups the user belongs to.

Here's the code which gets username/

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/print-username")
    public ResponseEntity<String> printUsername(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
        if (principal == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("User not authenticated", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("User Attributes:\n");

        // Print user attributes
        Map<String, Object> attributes = principal.getAttributes();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
            stringBuilder.append(entry.getKey()).append(": ").append(entry.getValue()).append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

        // Print user roles (authorities)
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = principal.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            System.out.println("Authority: " + authority.getAuthority());
        }

        // Get the username from the email attribute (assuming email is the user identifier)
        String username = (String) attributes.get("email");
        System.out.println("Username: " + username);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Username printed in the server console", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to get the groups for a user from OKTA from a Spring Boot app?

Comment: You won't be able to extract it unless it fused into id_token as a claim

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm trying to figure this out and have gotten a vague idea that claims are part of a JWTtoken, but I don't have a way forward yet.

Comment: group information can be made a part of id_token if it's configured this way on authZ server side, and also requested by a client with a respective scope. I believe there is a guide from Okta related to that. https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-groups-claim/main/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a groups claim in Okta by going to your admin console and navigating to **Security** > **API**. Select your authorization server and go to the **Claims** tab.

- Name: `groups`
- Include in: `ID Token`
- Value type: `Groups`
- Filter: Select `Matches regex` and use `.*` as the value

Then, click Create.

Then, if you're using the [Okta Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot), your groups will automatically be converted to Spring Security authorities. If you want to use a name other than `groups`, you can change that via [properties](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot#configure-your-properties).

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the comment. I will check it out when I get chance, hopefully later this week.

Comment: Hi Matt, can you please check this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76931736/how-to-convert-spring-boot-app-with-okta-to-read-okta-groups

Comment: @JackBeNimble I added an answer on your post.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was correct. The problem I had was I did't select "matches regex". See linked post for details.