# How to convert spring boot app with Okta to read okta groups

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, okta, claims

A while back, I created a spring book application that uses Okta as the OIDC provider. It's based on a previous version of [this great example](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/06/17/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot) by Matt Raible.

What I'm trying to do now is obtain the group or roles for the logged in user.

Matt responded to [Spring Boot / Okta - how to retrieve the users groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824137/spring-boot-okta-how-to-retrieve-the-users-groups) saying I should add claims to Okta interface, which I've done.

He qualified it, saying

> Then, if you're using the Okta Spring Boot starter, your groups will automatically be converted to Spring Security authorities.

I converted to Spring Boot starter kit, with the following steps:

1. Added the starter kit to pom.xml
2. changed application properties to use variables from the starter kit as follows:

   ```
   #okta spring boot starter kit

   okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default

   okta.oauth2.audience=api://default

   okta.oauth2.groupsClaim=groups

   #okta spring boot starter kit test

   okta.oauth2.clientId=xxxxxxxxxxxx

   okta.oauth2.clientSecret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   ```

And it works as it did before.

However, when I print the Authorities, I still don't see the groups. The only authority I see is this:

Authority: ROLE_USER
Username: xxxxx@gmail.com

Heres the code which prints the authorities:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = principal.getAuthorities();
for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
    System.out.println("Authority: " + authority.getAuthority());
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Here's an image of the claims:
[image: Claims]

Comment: See my updated answer after your question update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that adding the `groupsClaim` property would automatically map values to authorities. Are you sure you're adding it to the ID token?

The following technique is what we use in [JHipster](https://www.jhispter.tech), which uses Spring Security w/o the Okta starter.

Add a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` bean in your security configuration.

```java
/**
 * Map authorities from "groups" or "roles" claim in ID Token.
 *
 * @return a {@link GrantedAuthoritiesMapper} that maps groups from
 * the IdP to Spring Security Authorities.
 */
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
    return (authorities) -> {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        authorities.forEach(authority -> {
            // Check for OidcUserAuthority because Spring Security 5.2 returns
            // each scope as a GrantedAuthority, which we don't care about.
            if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority) {
                OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(SecurityUtils.extractAuthorityFromClaims(oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo().getClaims()));
            }
        });
        return mappedAuthorities;
    };
}
```

The relevant methods from `SecurityUtils` are:

```java
public static List<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorityFromClaims(Map<String, Object> claims) {
    return mapRolesToGrantedAuthorities(getRolesFromClaims(claims));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Collection<String> getRolesFromClaims(Map<String, Object> claims) {
    return (Collection<String>) claims.getOrDefault("groups",
        claims.getOrDefault("roles",
        claims.getOrDefault(CLAIMS_NAMESPACE + "roles", new ArrayList<>())));
}

private static List<GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToGrantedAuthorities(Collection<String> roles) {
    return roles.stream()
        .filter(role -> role.startsWith("ROLE_"))
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: If he's building a resource server (like you do in the tutorial he linked), shouldn't claims be added to access token (not ID token)? Also, I understand that, as an Okta employee, you favor the "Okta" starter, but maybe should you give ["my" starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) a try (I believe it to be more portable and to ease a wider range of use-cases).

Comment: You are correct that a resource server will only look at the access token. My solution will only work if you're using `oauth2Login()`.

Comment: "My" starter maps authorities the same way on OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login` ;) only the dependencies change (need `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`) and properties: spring boot oauth2 client properties and few additional ones from my lib, for instance when the OP is not strictly compliant with RP-Initiated logout (missing `end_session_endpoint` in OpenID config) or requires non standard query parameters on authorization code request (like `audience`). Samples on my repo main README.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answers - how do I check if i'm using oauth2Login? Under Claims I have "Name" is "groups",  "include in token type" is "ID Token" selected with "Always" as the value. The Value type is "groups", filter is "Starts with .*", include in is "Any Scope".  Is that correct? I added a picture in the post.

Comment: If you are building a resource server (REST API secured with **access token**), then you should add your private claims to access token for it to be used by Spring Security (not ID token like you did). `oauth2Login` is in Spring configuration for OAuth2 clients (secured with sessions, not access tokens, and with user details built from ID token or userinfo endpoint).

Comment: Hi Matt - This was a user error.. I had configured claims as "startsWith" instead of "Matches Regex".  At least, the claims are printed out as an array in the "groups" entry of the UserAttributes in the "print-username" method. Better yet, I didn't have to use the spring starter kit nor change any application properties. I think the claims might have been pulled in under the pre-existing "profile" scope in the app properties.

Answer (score 0):

#### Some OAuth2 backround

A resource server (REST API authorizing requests using Authorization header with Bearer token) is interested in access tokens, not ID tokens which are intended to be used by OAuth2 clients. So you should add your private claims to access tokens if you intend to use it on a resource server (not ID tokens like you did before taking the screenshot in your question).

Spring applications configured as OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login` are secured with session cookies (not access tokens) and retrieve user details from ID token (or userinfo endpoint when ID token is not available). Only in that case does it make sense to enrich ID token. Use case can be applications with server-side rendered UI (Thymeleaf, JSF, etc.) or [`spring-cloud-gateway` configured as BFF](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) (relay used in front of Javascript based applications, replacing session cookie with access tokens before forwarding requests to resource servers).

The tutorial you link depends on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, but also on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. As it uses `oauth2Login`, the `SecurityFilterChain` is actually an OAuth2 client one and requests are secured with sessions, not access tokens. This is not a recommended way to configure REST APIs: stateless resource servers scale much better (sessions use resources and you have to use something like Spring Session to share sessions across instances).

Configuring a REST API as an OAuth2 client (in which case you should remove `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` from your dependencies) can be a way to implement the BFF pattern, but it is certainly better to use a separate lightweight layer (`spring-cloud-gateway`) in front of regular resource server APIs.

For more OAuth2 background, refer to [my tutorials intro](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials).

#### Spring resource server with authorities mapping

As an alternative to Okta Spring Boot starter, you could use [mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which works with **any OpenID Provider**. All you need is opening one of your tokens with a tool like https://jwt.io to figure out the JSON path of claim(s) you want to use as source for Spring authorities.

Sample for a resource server (REST API secured with access token like in the tutorial you link), assuming that authorities are to be built from `groups` claim (under root node), adding `ROLE_` prefix to use `hasRole(...)` rather than `hasAuthority(...)`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <!-- in a reactive application, use spring-boot-starter-webflux instead -->
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
// In a reactive app, use @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity instead
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {
}
```

```yaml
issuer: https://dev-xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default
# client-id and client-secret are not used by resource servers with JWT decoders

# defining origins is optional, it is used for CORS configuration
origins: http://localhost:3000

# Spring boot properties for resource servers are ignored (not adapted to multi-tenant scenarios)

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        # this is an array, you can add all the OpenID Providers you trust
        - iss: ${issuer}
          # optional: it adds an audience validator to JWT decoder
          aud: api://default
          # optional: sub is a default you can replace with something relevant to your domain
          username-claim: sub
          authorities:
          # this is an array, you can add as many claims as you like
          - path: $.groups
            prefix: ROLE_
          # for illustration purpose: map roles claims without altering it with a prefix
          - path: $.roles
          # for illustration again: map all roles claims nested in an object (under a "domain" in Okta or Auth0)
          - path: $.*.roles
        resourceserver:
          # routes defined there will be accessible to anonymous requests
          # those not listed will require requests to be authorized
          permit-all:
          - "/public/**"
          - "/actuator/health/readiness"
          - "/actuator/health/liveness"
          - "/v3/api-docs/**"
          # optional: fine grained CORS configuration (per path matcher)
          cors:
          - path: /**
            allowed-origin-patterns: ${origins}
```

As you can see in the code above, the only things specific to Okta are the issuer URI and JSON path to claims to extract authorities from. Switching to any other OIDC provider (Auth0, Keycloak, Amazon Cognito, etc.) is just a matter of editing this properties.

#### Spring client with authorities mapping

As wrote above, this should stand in a gateway configuration rather than in a REST API. See my [BFF tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
issuer: https://dev-xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default
okta-client-id: change-me
okta-client-secret: change-me

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          okta:
            issuer-uri: ${issuer}
        registration:
          okta-confidential-user:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${okta-client-id}
            client-secret: ${okta-client-secret}
            provider: okta
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access,roles

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${issuer}
          authorities:
          - path: $.groups
            prefix: ROLE_
          - path: $.roles
          - path: $.*.roles
        client:
          security-matchers: 
          - /**
          permit-all:
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          csrf: cookie-accessible-from-js
          oauth2-logout:
            okta-confidential-user:
              uri: ${issuer}/login/signout
              post-logout-uri-request-param: fromURI
```

This will configure an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` (and logout).

Comment: In my pom.xml, it references ouath2 dependencies. Also, I don't see any bearer tokens in the API calls, but there are JSESSIONID and XRSF-TOKEN cookies. Does this mean it's an oauth2 app? 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>

Comment: `spring-security-oauth2-client` => OAuth2 client. This is not adapted to REST APIs. As answered, this is adapted to applications with server-side rendering (Thymeleaf, JSP, JSF, ...) or when configuring a BFF. Configure your REST APIs as resource servers and put a gateway configured as BFF in front of it for Javascript based applications (Angular, React, Vue, ...), as done in my tutorials.

Comment: It has a react front-end that uses REST APIS. This all comes from the tutorial I referenced (version from a few years ago).   I just built it up for my own purposes. It's worked like a champ, but now I need to do some extra processing based on the user groups, which is why I'm trying to get them.

Comment: Here's a REST api call to delete a license: 

async remove(id) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this license?')) {

    await fetch(`/api/license/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.state.csrfToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include'
    }).then(() => {
      let updatedLicenses = [...this.state.licenses].filter(i => i.id !== id);
      this.setState({licenses: updatedLicenses});
    });
  }

Comment: I'm not saying your wrong by any stretch, it's just that I can't find any bearer tokens in the API calls to examine. I do like the idea of a library that doesn't bind you to a single provider. But for now, I'm just trying to get the groups.

Comment: Of course you're not finding a bearer token: you have configured your REST API as an OAuth2 client => it is secured with session cookies as stated in my answer. Just get some more education about OAuth2 actors (client, resource server, resource owner and authorization server), and about how a **REST API** should be configured if you want it to scale. Also get some info about the BFF pattern and why it should be preferred over using public clients running in a browser. And don't trust just me, or Matt Raible, or a blogger, also read the specs and Spring Security doc.

Comment: Oh, ok. In your answer, I thought you were saying the opposite. This is clear: "you have configured your REST API as an OAuth2 client => it is secured with session cookies" 

That's what I was seeing as well went I went through the code and the APIs. Now I think you're saying (not sure) that I should change the app around to not do that. I'm hoping that's not necessary.